# cross account SNS topic publish

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, aws-cdk

I have an SNS topic in account A that takes an error and sends to pager duty

I have another account - Account B that has several services in it, fargate, SQS etc but I have several cloudwatch alarms / actions setup to publish alerts to this SNS topic in account A

I get this error on Account B (the one trying to access the cross account service)

> Failed to execute action
> arn:aws:ACCOUNT-A:sns-topic.
> Received error: "Resource:
> arn:aws:cloudwatch:ACCOUNT-B
> is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource:
> ACCOUNT-A:sns"

here is my AWS CDK code for Account A

```
const accountATopic= new sns.Topic(this, 'accountATopic', {
   displayName: 'accountATopic'
 });
 accountATopic.addSubscription(new snsSubscriptions.UrlSubscription('Externalurl'));
 
 accountATopic.grantPublish(new iam.AccountPrincipal('ACCOUNTB'));
```

and then in ACCOUNT B (not showing the alarms)

```
 const ACCOUNTBTopic = sns.Topic.fromTopicArn(this, 'ACCOUNTBTopic ', 'ACCOUNT-A-ARN');
      const action = new cloudwatchActions.SnsAction(ACCOUNTBTopic );



      ACCOUNTBTopic .addToResourcePolicy(new PolicyStatement({
        resources: ['ACCOUNT-A-ARN'],
        actions: ['SNS:Publish'],
        effect: Effect.ALLOW,
        }))
```

Comment: Hello @SightSoundM -  grant in account A should be done for the role in account b, not the account itself. See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-cross-account-ec2-instance-iam-role/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone that comes across this in the future - here is what I did to get it working:

```
    const accountATopic= new sns.Topic(this, 'accountATopic', {
   displayName: 'accountATopic'
 });
 accountATopic.addSubscription(new snsSubscriptions.UrlSubscription('Externalurl'));
 
  let snsPolicy = new PolicyStatement({effect:Effect.ALLOW,
      resources:[accountATopic.topicArn],
      actions:["SNS:Publish"],
      principals:[
      new AccountPrincipal('ACCOUNTB_ID'),
     ]
    })
      //or optionally:
    //snsPolicy.addAnyPrincipal()


      accountATopic.addToResourcePolicy(snsPolicy)
```

The grant publish method does not seem to allow it to work, also according to [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Cross-Account-Cross-Region.html#enable-cross-account-cross-Region) on cross account SNS / CloudWatch they suggested adding the org id for a condition - this did not work for me and had to remove it